# Working with query strings in Nancy

Tags: nancy

I'm new to Nancy,

I see I can work with the query string using `Request.Query.Foo` and check for the existence of the value via `Request.Query.Foo.HasValue`. If I try to read Foo and it does not exist, does Nancy return null or does it throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foo will be of type [DynamicDictionaryValue](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/DynamicDictionaryValue.cs), so you will actually need to access the Value property to use it, just as you would a Nullable type. It won't simply throw an error for referencing Request.Query.Foo unless you try to do something with the .Value and it is null.

Comment: Oh, I see there is a DefaultValue which will help me guard.